# How do I connect from Cloud Run to Cloud SQL, and external traffic via a static egress IP?

Tags: java, postgresql, google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-run, google-cloud-networking

We're using Google Cloud Run with a java app to store data in Cloud Sql Postgres. We need to connect to external services using a static IP.

We are connecting to the database using the example code provided in [the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-run), with the following connection string: `jdbc:postgresql:///<DB_NAME>?unixSocketPath=</PATH/TO/UNIX/SOCKET>&cloudSqlInstance=<CLOUD_SQL_CONNECTION_NAME>& // socketFactory=com.google.cloud.sql.postgres.SocketFactory&user=<DB_USER>&password=<DB_PASS>`. In the Cloud Run service we pointed the Cloud SQL connections to the database. This works well.

To add a static egress IP to the Cloud Run service, we followed the [guide to Static outbound IP address](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/static-outbound-ip).

We're running a test service that shows the external IP, and again, this shows the static external IP.

The problem is that now the connection to the database does not work anymore.

To fix this, we removed the `unixSocketPath` from the database connection string, resulting in `jdbc:postgresql:///<DB_NAME>?cloudSqlInstance=<CLOUD_SQL_CONNECTION_NAME>& // socketFactory=com.google.cloud.sql.postgres.SocketFactory&user=<DB_USER>&password=<DB_PASS>`.

Now the following problem pops up, once in a while:

```
Failed to create ephemeral certificate for the Cloud SQL instance.
```

We believe this is due to Cloud Run throttling our service to near 0 when not in use, as alluded to in [this reply](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-jdbc-socket-factory/issues/502#issuecomment-846081718) in the socket factory github issues. This problem did not happen when connecting over the unix socket.

Stumped, we tried to minimise code and dependencies, resulting in the following test project: https://gist.github.com/goulashify/b05593dceae717e425b097f3fe840883

What are we missing? Is there a way to connect to the outside world using a static ip, *and* have a reliable connection to Cloud Sql?

Comment: This is actually looking like an unintended limitation on the GCP side. I would advise you to open a [Bug Report in Google's Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=608076&template=0), so that google's engineering became aware of this an work toward fixing this.

Comment: Thanks, done: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/199185678

Comment: For what it's worth, we recently made the SocketFactory more reliable ([context](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-jdbc-socket-factory/issues/528#issuecomment-886883795)) when used on Cloud Run with 0 minimum instances. Are you seeing any connection failures with the current approach?

Comment: We cannot use the unix socket because the recommended-by-the-documentation way of routing egress traffic over a static IP breaks the connection entirely. The only way to connect to Postgres while also using static egress IP is to use the tcp socket, and this still breaks when throttled in Cloud Run.

Comment: When you say "breaks," do you mean you're seeing connectivity issues? Or are you seeing the ephemeral cert failing to refresh?

Comment: We still need to test with the latest release, will report back